# Show error as alert on firebase authentication with react native

Tags: reactjs, native

I am using this function in my react native app but it crashes my app, though it shows me errors on my emulator as a console, how shall i use alert to show whatever the error is to the user instead of crashing the app?

```
  signup =(email,password) =>{
try{
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)

    .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('home')) } 
    catch(error){
        alert("not valid"`enter code here`)
    }

   }
```

Comment: How about displaying the **alert(error.message);** as JSX instead of alert?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can Display your custom alert messages using the switch case on error codes:

```
import {Alert} from 'react-native';

   try{
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
      .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('home'))
      .catch(error => {   
        switch(error.code) {
          case 'auth/email-already-in-use':
                Alert.alert('Email already in use !')
                break;
       }
     })
   }catch(err){
      alert("Error : ", err);
   }
```

If you want to display the message directly from firebase :

```
   try{
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
      .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('home'))
      .catch(error => {   
        alert(error.message);
     })
   }catch(err){
      alert(err);
   }
```

Comment: I have updated the answer, please have a look.  @SḧîṫíźGủṗṫā

Comment: HEY!!! thanks buddy, this one finally worked for me!! : try{
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
      .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('home'))
      .catch(error => {   
        alert(error.message);
     })
   }catch(err){
      alert(err);
   }

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
 signup =(email,password) =>{
     try{
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
          .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('home'))
          .catch(error => {
           alert("Error occurred", error)
         })
       }catch(err){
          alert("Error occurred", err);
        }
   }
```

Comment: i want to show that particular error itself, how is that possible sir?

Comment: Aren't you getting alert with particular error in alert with my code?

Comment: yes i get alert sir, i get  the alert which says "Error Occured"

Comment: i want instead of this string, it displays the actual error, for example : email is in wrong format,  or password should be more than 6 letters ... etc etc.

Comment: @SḧîṫíźGủṗṫā Have you tried the validation yourself? if not please search in the internet there are thousands of articles and SO answers available about how to validate email and password. Please do your homework and come back if you face any difficulties

Comment: i have tried validation sir, it works for me fine, the records show up properly on the firebase console

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use an async function or a promise within a try block i have done that before and it resulted to the same issue as urs u should use only then and catch and try removing the try statement i hope it helps